# finding a function consisting of two variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Some context beforehand:- I was writing an expression for force between two charges with two mediums placed in between them. I noticed that the deviation of the force I calculated to be varying by a constant factor at particular distances from the actual value of force.

I know the expression for the actual force but I wanted to take this opportunity to learn a way of finding what the expression for that factor would be knowing their magnitudes at 2 different distances. That leads me to this question where r is the distance between them and t is the distance covered by another medium.

I need to find a function $f(r,t)$ such that

$$f(r,t) = \begin{cases} 2, & t=\frac{r}{2},& r\ge t>0\\
                   r, &  t=r, & r\ge t>0\\
                 \end{cases}$$

The question really is straightforward but I don't have any mathematical approach to this so in reality I just wasted an hour manually trying out different possible functions. can someone tell me how I can conclusively find the function or disprove the existence of the function?

I wrote several functions such as $2+t(2-\frac{4}{r})$, $\frac{4r}{t+r}$, $\frac{r}{r-t}$

I don't see the point of writing more but ultimately I still couldn't find any function that fulfills both the conditions.

p.s- hope the formatting is better this time.

Comment: It seems to be difficult to get $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(0,0)=f(0,0/2)=2$ simultaneously for $r=0$, since a funcction can only evaluate to one value per point.

Comment: my bad i should've mentioned that r>0
and t<r

Comment: If you worked for an hour then please show some of that work, so that we know what you’ve already tried. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). And in general, see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: alright im sorry. this is my first post. ill go through it and update the post asap

Comment: For $t<r$ the expression $f(r,r)$ is not defined, since then $t=r$. But that's not really a problem. Why don't you take $f$ given by $f(r,t)=r$ for $t=r$ and $f(r,t)=2$ otherwise? That should do the trick. Or do you want $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: I didn't quite get why would it not be defined. it would be undefined if theres a r-t term in the denominator or were you trying to say something else? |
as for the other suggestion it shouldnt return only these two values. now that i've given more context to the physical meaning of the function. it should return 2 or r only at that particular point.

Comment: How can you be in the second case $t=r$ if $r>t$?

Comment: that was the extreme case i have updated the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let,
$$f(r,t)=2\sin\left(\frac{t}{r}\pi\right)+r\sin\left(\frac{t}{r}\pi-\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)$$

Then,
\begin{align}
f(r,r/2)&=2\sin\left(\frac{r/2}{r}\pi\right)+r\sin\left(\frac{r/2}{r}\pi-\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)\\
&=2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)+r\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi-\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)\\
&=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+r\sin\left(0\right)\\
&=2\cdot1+r\cdot0\\
&=2
\end{align}
and,
\begin{align}
f(r,r)&=2\sin\left(\frac{r}{r}\pi\right)+r\sin\left(\frac{r}{r}\pi-\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)\\
&=2\sin\left(\pi\right)+r\sin\left(\pi-\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)\\
&=2\sin\left(\pi\right)+r\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&=2\cdot 0+r\cdot1\\
&=r
\end{align}
as required.

Comment: wow i didn't even think of trigonometric functions. can you describe briefly on what approach you used to get that expression? just trial and error?

Comment: Like you I started off trying rational functions, but saw that I kept needing to add terms to get the desired effect to satisfy either condition. I assumed this would continue on forever creating an infinite polynomial which would probably converge to some other function, such as the taylor series of $\sin(x)$ or $e^x$. Then I was reminded of Willans' formula for primes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) and how he used regular expressions as detector functions. After that basically just trial and error.